# Running Boost's built in tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, boost

Is `./b2 status` the correct way to run the tests that come with Boost? To test the libraries themselves?

Related question. Is it generally a good idea to run a libraries test suite, or can the designers be trusted to have run it themselves before deploying?

Answer (score 6):

You can run *all* the Boost unit tests with:

```
cd <boost-root>/status
b2
```

Or you can also:

```
cd <boost-root>/libs/<a-library>/test
b2
```

And all most of the unit tests are run continuously as part of library development. You can see the results of the tests in the [regression test results](http://www.boost.org/development/testing.html#RegressionTesting). Note that libraries can also have extended tests that are not generally run. You would need to consult the particular library docs to see how to run the additional tests.

Comment: For msys2/mingw-w64, I had to use `b2 toolset=gcc status`

Comment: I find that the second suggestion (for a single library) produces the message "error: no Jamfile in current directory found, and no target references specified."

Comment: It seems by default running a test this way will print the output (`cerr` or `cout`) only in case of errors. Is there a way to tell `b2` to print it in any case?